# How to integrate Harness CCM with Datadog

Tags: azure, azure-devops, datadog, tap-harness

Currently I have setup a Connector for my Azure Account for cost analysis on Harness CCM portal. We have limited access to Harness So wanted to integrate this with Datadog where we have access to larger number of audience in our organization.

How can I make a start on this request?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting Harness to Datadog is fairly straightforward. Harness has a first class integration with Datadog for CCM data. ([Link to Integration](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/harness_cloud_cost_management/))

Since you already have the Azure connector setup, navigating to the Harness Cloud Cost Management Dashboard and authenticating one of the widgets by logging in with your Harness user ID should enable the data to start showing up within Datadog. Here's a example of the [Datadog CCM dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0sjY.png).

Harness Cloud Cost management also exposes REST APIs for added flexibility. [Link to API docs](https://harness.io/docs/api/tag/Cloud-Cost-Details)